# Web App that can connect/disconnect?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-applications, mobile

I'm very new to web apps so this might be a really silly question. Basically I want to have a web app which synchs with a database, it also should be able to send data which will be synched with a database.

My question is about downtime. If the web app loses its net connection, is there a way for it to save the information inputted into it until it regains a net connection and can synch it to th database?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This very much depends. While the client side page is open you can of course just keep any data there until you can re-open an ajax dialogue with the server. Once the user closes the page, however, your options become more limited - off the top of my head all I can think of is a cookie, and that's just 4096 bytes. Perhaps consider a backup server that could save the data until the primary server is accessible again?

Comment: Just realised - you start talking about web apps but finish the question talking about mobile apps. If you're designing a fully fledged android/iphone/blackberry/etc app, your client-side data storage options are obviously much better: sqlite dbs, etc. Even for web apps thought you might be able to use something like this: http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2005/10/21/store-large-data-client-side-with-amass/ (although it looks a bit iffy to me)

Comment: sorry that was a mistake, I didn't mean to say mobile app. so if the page remains open and information is input that's fine? I guess that's the best I could hope for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you want to write an http fifo queue using HTML5 local storage. It's very overkill in most situations but at work we have a native client library for iOS, WP7, Android and Javascript and all offer persistent queuing and reliable delivery so they have to handle the server connection dropping out for whatever reason.

Get/Post -> In to In-Memory queue -> Save to storage -> Send -> remove from storage -> raise "sent" callback.

If a message fails to send then leave it in storage and requeue it in memory.

Have a timer event that kicks the queue every few seconds (As well as kicking it when messages are added/removed). Limit that max simultaneous connections (Http should be 2 per client).

Then each time your web app is loaded try read all items in local storage back in to the In-Memory queue.

Then you have persistent/reliable queuing and won't lose any messages :)

Comment: oh right and this actually works with iOS, WP7 and Android? Cos I don't think WP7 has HTML5 support yet...

Comment: Native to each platform - So WP7 is .Net, iOS Objective C etc. and our Webapp is Javascript/HTML5 :) All achieve the same thing and expose the same API to developers.